# How to display user structure

Tags: angular

I have here such a model:

```
export class User{
    constructor(
        public user_id?:number,
        public name?: string,
        public position?: string,
    ) { }
}
```

And I want to derive from this model a structure similar to this [one](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html).
What is the component in Angular 2+ to output a similar structure?

And how can  use the component you proposed not for such a model:

```
public org_ChartData = [
        ['Name', 'Manager', 'ToolTip'],
        [{ v: 'Mike', f: 'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>' },
            '', 'The President'],
        [{ v: 'Jim', f: 'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President</div>' },
            'Mike', 'VP'],
        ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
        ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
        ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
    ]
```

but for my model shown above. I just never did such a scheme before and generally did not use the chartjs, so do not judge strictly if that.

Comment: Angular does not provide such a component

Comment: Is there a good workaround that looks like this one?

Comment: Why not use gojs?

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can do that.
But in order to display a structor, I highly recommend you to spend sometimes and look up to Composite pattern [here](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/composite-design-pattern)

So your structure above will be some thing similar like this one.

```
export class User{
 constructor(
   public user_id?:number,
   public name?: string,
   public position?: string,
 ) { }

 users: User[];

 logInfor() {
   console.log([this.user_id, this.name, this.position].join('')];
   // Here is the child composite
   users.forEach((user: User) => user.logInfor());
 }
}
```

Then your org_ChartData could be come a composite.
And for the component to be able to render the chart.
You just have to create a 'UserCardComponent' which render single 'User' and the 'OrgChartComponent' which is the schema above to Render the 'Chart'
And I guess in order to create the 'User' hierarchy from the json above could be pretty easy for you though, just loop and loop.
Hope it would help you a bits.